# Positive lookbehind after negative lookbehind

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Regex: (?<!xx)(?<=34)56(?=78) with global flag

12345678

xx345678

Why does it match 56 on both lines? Shouldn't (?<!xx) exclude second line?

Comment: No, because the several lookarounds are executed at the same location

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what should I change to make this regex work as I wanted?

Comment: `(?<!xx\d*)(?<=34)56(?=78)` or `(?<!xx.*)(?<=34)56(?=78)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex with a nested negative lookbehind:

```sh
(?<=(?<!xx)34)56(?=78)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1U82Qo/1)

`(?<!xx)` inside the `(?<=(?<!xx)34)` will assert failure if `xx` is positioned just before `34`.